# Python using a list as variable to create SQL table

Tags: python, sql, list, variables

I have a list that I would like to use to create SQL table. This list will be variable so that I can dynamically create SQL tables without typing the columns and data types.

```
sqltablecode = ['ACK_ID VARCHAR (255)',
 'SF_PLAN_YEAR_BEGIN_DATE DATE',
 'SF_TAX_PRD VARCHAR (255)',
 'SF_PLAN_ENTITY_CD VARCHAR (255)']
```

Code to create SQL table:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))")
```

My goal is to make the SQL code for the table variable.

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE customers ({sqltablecode})")
```

If this is possible, I would like to know how to escape the variable from the CREATE TABLE statement. Also will python read the list with quotes `'ACK_ID VARCHAR (255)','SF_PLAN_YEAR_BEGIN_DATE DATE'` or as `ACK_ID VARCHAR (255),SF_PLAN_YEAR_BEGIN_DATE DATE`. I will need a way to get the later so that it can be in SQL format.

Comment: did you mean to use f string? `mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE customers ({sqltablecode})")`

Comment: This was my result MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['ACK_ID VARCHAR (255)', 'SF_PLAN_YEAR_BEGIN_DATE DATE', 'SF_TAX_PRD VARCHAR (25' at line 1.

Comment: `f"CREATE TABLE customers ({', '.join(sqltablecode)})"`.

Comment: ProgrammingError: 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs.

Comment: Some of the tables I want to create can have up to 135 columns, Is this too much to handle?

Comment: use `f"CREATE TABLE customers ({sqltablecode}` as suggested by @SuperStew, but put your SQL in a string, not a list

Comment: @gimix , making the SQL into a string worked and using SuperStews' f string worked! Thanks !